# gradle - Minimize json resources in processResources

Tags: java, json, gradle, groovy

I'm currently working on a project. The resources for the project contain a lot of json files which all end up in the final jar. I am already processing the resouces. Like renaming files and replacing certain strings in some other files. So the `processResources` task is already being used.

Now the question is how I could expand it in order for it to minimize all the json files. Since Groovy itself has json utilities, having the ability to get the files contents and replacing them in the destination should be enough to make everything work.

This is my current `processResources` task:

```
processResources {
    // this will ensure that this task is redone when the versions change.
    inputs.property "version", project.version
    inputs.property "mcversion", project.minecraft.version

    // replace stuff in mcmod.info, nothing else
    from(sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs) {
        include "mcmod.info"

        // replace version and mcversion
        expand "version": project.version, "mcversion": project.minecraft.version
    }

    // Minify json resources
    from(sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs) {
        include "**/*.json"

        // Minify every file here
    }

    // copy everything else, thats not the mcmod.info
    from(sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs) {
        exclude "mcmod.info"
        exclude "**/*.json"
    }

    rename "(.+_at.cfg)", 'META-INF/$1'

    from MainDirResources
}
```

Minimizing the files should work with any of the following two lines:

```
JsonOutput.toJson(new JsonSlurper().parseText( <file content here> ))
JsonOutput.toJson(new JsonSlurper().parse( <file here> ))
```

So what do I have to do to get the content of all files or all instances of the files themselves and modify their contents in the output dir?

Comment: Gradle can run an executable file, you can write a shell script to minimize the json files (remove new lines), then execute it within your gradle script.

Comment: @AlecZhang I'd like to avoid using the shell where I can. Also as I said minimizing the JSON itself shouldn't be to hard: http://groovy-lang.org/json.html

Comment: How do you intend to minify them?

Comment: @tim_yates ``JsonOutput.toJson(new JsonSlurper().parseText( <file content here> ))`` or ``JsonOutput.toJson(new JsonSlurper().parse( <file here> ))``

Answer (score 5):

The following does the trick:

```
processResources {
    // this will ensure that this task is redone when the versions change.
    inputs.property "version", project.version
    inputs.property "mcversion", project.minecraft.version

    // replace stuff in mcmod.info, nothing else
    from(sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs) {
        include "mcmod.info"

        // replace version and mcversion
        expand "version": project.version, "mcversion": project.minecraft.version
    }

    // copy everything else, thats not the mcmod.info
    from(sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs) {
        exclude "mcmod.info"
    }

    from MainDirResources

    rename "(.+_at.cfg)", 'META-INF/$1'

    // Minify json resources
    doLast {
        fileTree(dir: outputs.files.asPath, include: "**/*.json").each {
            File file -> file.text = JsonOutput.toJson(new JsonSlurper().parse(file))
        }
    }
}
```

Since `outputs.files` only contains a single dir (the dir the files get copied to) you can turn it into a file tree and iterate over the files and the minize the json files. Should be run as last operation in `processResources` though